# Installing pip install requests and pip install bs4

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I have tried several methods to install the following libraries on spyder(Python 3.7).

```
pip install requests
pip install bs4
```

But I got the following errors:

```
 File "C:/Users/asith/untitled1.py", line 1
    pip install requests
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and

```
  File "C:/Users/asith/untitled1.py", line 2
    pip install bs4
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The `pip install Foo` command is not executed in scripts but in the console/terminal/CMD. Execute `python -m pip install requests bs4`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one of two ways
1. run your code in your console evn by doing:

```sh
source your/script/path.sh
```

2.
change the lines in the script to:

```sh
python -m pip install <package-name>
```